# How to avoid memory error when using np.kron to generate a big matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I try to write a matrix consisting of kronecker-products

```
def kron_sparse_2(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p):
    kron= sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(sparse.kron(a,b),c),d),e),f),g),h),i),j),k),l),m),n),o),p)
    return kron

res = 0
for i in sd:
     res= res +( kron_sparse_2(i,i,I,I,I,I,I,I,I,I,I,I,I,I,I,I))
```

The i's in sd are 2x2 matrices.
Is there anything I can do further to calculate this without the memory problem?

The error I get is: `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 16.0 GiB for an array with shape (536870912, 2, 2) and data type float64`

Comment: Nope.  You will have to figure out another way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (I think you are trying to form the Hamiltonian for some spin problem, and you should be able to go up to 20 spins with ease. Also if it is indeed the case try using np.roll and reduce functions to rewrite your methods efficiently), you might try converting all of your matrices (even with dims. 2X2) to sparse format (say csr or csc) and use scipy kron function with the format specified as the sparse matrix format you used to construct all of your matrices. Because as far as I remember kron(format=None) uses an explicit representation of matrices which causes memory problems, try format='csc' for instance.